# Understanding managed VNet using Private Endpoint for azure data factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm working on writing some basic azure data factory pipelines, and i'm new to this.

We have a private network behind a firewall, with an on-prem sql server database I'm connecting to. I thought I could use a self-hosted runtime, but when I try to run a data flow, it instead tells me I need to use a "managed VNet using Private Endpoint. "

I read the microsoft doc on it and still can't quite wrap my head around what this is, and if I actually need it. The self-hosted runtime seems to allow me to connect to the server, just not run a data flow, so I'm confused what the difference is.

Does it sound like I actually need to go down this route, and if so, any tips on how to implement? TY!

read MS docs but couldn't understand

Comment: If your data source is on-prem and behind a firewall, then self-hosted integration runtime is the right approach. Can you post the error\issue you see when trying to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I created self-hosted integration runtime and connected on-premises sql server successfully.

[image]

I created dataset with above linked service and tried to use that in dataflow got below error:

[image]

I found that as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#integration-runtime-types) self-hosted integration runtime is not supported for dataflow. If we want to use on premises sql database data copy that data to azure data lake or blob storage through copy activity trough self-hosted integrated runtime and use otherwise use the Azure IR with managed vnet. To create that you can follow this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server).